# Secondary linear lamp circuit interrupter switch

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, interrupts, linear, circuit-theory

Following on from [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/334268/83512) to a [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/334246/83512) from a while back, I want to add a new lamp (with its own button/switch).

1. The new lamp should be controlled separately (i.e. not controlled or affected by the timer).
2. When activated, the new lamp should emit a single flash.
3. Triggering the flash should interrupt/reset/disable the timer (if it's active), killing the lights.

The idea is to mimic the behaviour of a (photo) flash with auxiliary lighting that automatically cuts out when the flash fires. In reality flash lamps are usually high voltage xenon tubes. But for now I'm more interested in the switching, and the rest of the circuit so I'll just be using a regular incandescent bulb to demonstrate the concept.

---

[image: 20-Second MOSFET Timer]
<sup>***20-Second MOSFET Timer***</sup>

Comment: How long does the flash need to be?

Comment: @Trevor Trevor, mate. I was hoping you'd see this. You really helped me last time. The shorter the better, probably. I think usually anywhere between 1/60 sec - 1/250 sec. But it's not super important at this stage.

Comment: Meh forget it, at this point you would be better with a 555 type circuit...

Comment: @Trevor So people keep telling me. But it defeats the purpose of the exercise. I thought you (and one other person) understood that. Although, it would be useful to compare/contrast the two methods.

Comment: Sorry. Maybe I forgot, I'm old, so I can't remember if I did or not. There are discrete circuits that can do what you want, but the investment in effort required to volunteer a circuit for you and the lack of quality of said circuit is starting to outweigh the benefits of the alternative.  The simple delay circuit I originally gave you was a nice simple, all be it, inaccurate solution. Now your are adding more requirements that make that approach less and less suitable. Discrete solutions are typically very limited in their usefulness especially when simpler integrated solutions are available.

Comment: @Trevor Actually, I'm very fond of your original delay circuit. The results are consistent and easily adjustable with a potentiometer. I've learned a lot from trying to analyse it. Also, from what I've read, and been told, it sounds like 555 ICs are inaccurate and unreliable at best, but I wouldn't know personally. What is the meaning of *discrete* in this context?

Comment: Discrete means.. uses simple parts like R,C and Q. And yes, a 555 is not the best circuit in the world, because it is still more consistent than discrete parts. Your circuit probably works great on a sample of one. But if you build 100 of them, you will find they are all different.

Comment: I might revisit the discrete version later though.. just for fun ;)

Comment: @Trevor Cool. Yeah, I'm mainly focused on discrete solutions at the moment. I think I've been using the term *linear* to mean *discrete*. Some related questions you might remember: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/326300/83512 and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/325431/83512

Answer (score 1):

This really is not a free design service, but since you quoted my answer to your previous question, I'll give you one more freebie.

You could use this simple method.. The switch enables the flash through a cap so it will only be on a short time. D1 and R3 gives the cap a discharge path.

Meanwhile, the switch also pulls the gate of M1 low and discharges C1 through D2, killing your timer.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuQoVi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The flash would not be that bright though since the cap, unless it is very large, will likely charge faster than the lamp can heat up.

However, at this point you would be better to go for something a lot better controlled that gives you some manual adjustments like the 555 (556) circuit below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP1724.png)</sup>

Or better still use a small mirco that uses electron vapour to run.

Comment: Thanks for answering. For the record. I'm not really looking for a free design service. I'm not building a marketable product, and I'm not making a financial profit. I just come here to learn. Like everyone else, I imagine. And this is how I learn; something obscure piques my interest, and I ask weird (sometimes difficult) questions until I gain the understanding I'm looking for. More often than not, I'm met with negativity, ignorance, condescension, and even hostility. But every now and then someone helpful and encouraging will come along and I'll be refreshed and inspired.